# How do I set Typescript types for useReducer useContext for the following contextapi code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-typescript, use-reducer

Instead of any, I wanna use proper TS types in the following code. I 'm new to react TS, pls help...

How do I set typescript types for useReducer useContext for the following context API code:

```
import React, {createContext, Dispatch} from 'react';
import {firebaseUser} from '../@types/User';

interface Actions {
  SET_IMAGENAME: string;
  SET_USER: string;
}

export const Actions: Actions = {
  SET_IMAGENAME: 'SET_IMAGENAME',
  SET_USER: 'SET_USER',
};

function action(type: string) {
  return {type};
}

function actionPayload(type: string, payload: any) { //here
  return {type, payload};
}

export const Dispatches = {
  setImageName: action,
  setUser: actionPayload,
};

interface State {
  imgName: string;
  user: firebaseUser;
}

const initialState = {
  imgName: '',
  user: {} as firebaseUser,
};

function reducer(state = initialState, action: {type: string; payload: any}) { //here
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.SET_IMAGENAME:
      return {...state, imgName: 'sample image'};
    case Actions.SET_USER:
      return {...state, user: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const Store = createContext<{
  state: State;
  dispatch: Dispatch<any>; //here
}>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => null,
});

export function StoreProvider({children}: JSX.ElementChildrenAttribute): JSX.Element {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return <Store.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>{children}</Store.Provider>;
}
```

Could Anyone help me It will be appreciated?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depended on what can the payload contain, it can contain string for image or FirebaseUser instance you can set `payload: string | FirebaseUser`

```
import React, {createContext, Dispatch} from 'react';
import {firebaseUser} from '../@types/User';

interface Actions {
  SET_IMAGENAME: string;
  SET_USER: string;
}

export const Actions: Actions = {
  SET_IMAGENAME: 'SET_IMAGENAME',
  SET_USER: 'SET_USER',
};

function action(type: string) {
  return {type};
}

// If payload can contain string of image or FirebaseUser instance
// it will be string | FirebaseUser
// if payload will only contain FirebaseUser instance you just need payload: FirebaseUser
export type ActionType = {
 type: string,
 payload: string | FirebaseUser
}

// If payload can contain string of image or FirebaseUser instance
// it will be string | FirebaseUser
// if payload will only contain FirebaseUser instance you just need payload: FirebaseUser
function actionPayload(type: string, payload: string | FirebaseUser ) { //here
  return {type, payload};
}

export const Dispatches = {
  setImageName: action,
  setUser: actionPayload,
};

interface State {
  imgName: string;
  user: FirebaseUser;
}

const initialState = {
  imgName: '',
  user: {} as firebaseUser,
};

// set Action type here
function reducer(state = initialState, action: ActionType) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.SET_IMAGENAME:
      // need to cast type herer
      return {...state, imgName: action.payload as string};
    case Actions.SET_USER:
      // need to cast type herer
      return {...state, user: action.payload as firebaseUser};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const Store = createContext<{
  state: State;
  dispatch: Dispatch<ActionType>; //action type here
}>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => null,
});

export function StoreProvider({children}: JSX.ElementChildrenAttribute): JSX.Element {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return <Store.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>{children}</Store.Provider>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks of taking out time to help me, I still get error on state on the last line, can u pls check it? here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-ramanujan-jtrb3?file=/src/contextApi.tsx

Comment: @Sushilzzz we need to cast when setting state in reducer too. Please check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-mendel-19ev9?file=/src/contextApi.tsx

Answer (score 4):

I hope this solution will give good idea.

https://gist.github.com/sw-yx/f18fe6dd4c43fddb3a4971e80114a052

https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/#extended-example

```js
export function createCtx<StateType, ActionType>(
  reducer: React.Reducer<StateType, ActionType>,
  initialState: StateType,
) {
  const defaultDispatch: React.Dispatch<ActionType> = () => initialState // we never actually use this
  const ctx = React.createContext({
    state: initialState,
    dispatch: defaultDispatch, // just to mock out the dispatch type and make it not optioanl
  })
  function Provider(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>) {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer<React.Reducer<StateType, ActionType>>(reducer, initialState)
    return <ctx.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }} {...props} />
  }
  return [ctx, Provider] as const
}
// usage
const initialState = { count: 0 }
type AppState = typeof initialState
type Action =
  | { type: 'increment' }
  | { type: 'add'; payload: number }
  | { type: 'minus'; payload: number }
  | { type: 'decrement' }

function reducer(state: AppState, action: Action): AppState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return { count: state.count + 1 }
    case 'decrement':
      return { count: state.count - 1 }
    case 'add':
      return { count: state.count + action.payload }
    case 'minus':
      return { count: state.count - action.payload }
    default:
      throw new Error()
  }
}
const [ctx, CountProvider] = createCtx(reducer, initialState)
export const CountContext = ctx

// top level example usage
export function App() {
  return (
    <CountProvider>
      <Counter />
    </CountProvider>
  )
}

// example usage inside a component
function Counter() {
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(CountContext)
  return (
    <div>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'increment' })}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'add', payload: 5 })}>+5</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'decrement' })}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'minus', payload: 5 })}>+5</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is also my solution by adding types file to do more cleanness to your file structures here is it and I hope you find it useful :
[myCodesandboxRepo](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-colden-urkry?file=/src/App.tsx)